# Binding XAML controls to complex data type (PasswordCredential)

Tags: winrt-xaml, uwp, template10

I'm trying to create a Windows 10 app with a settings page that lets the user enter credentials the app will use to connect to an external service. I want to store those credentials in the PasswordVault.

I've used [Template10](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/wiki) Template10 as a starting point. I've added a TextBox and PasswordBox to the Settings PivotItem. I've added a PasswordCredential member to ISettingsService. And, I've added an implementation to the SettingsService class to store and retrieve a PasswordCredential object from the vault.

Now, I need to wire up the TextBox and PasswordBox to the UserName and Password properties of the PasswordCredental object. There's also some logic that needs to be executed when the username/password pair is updated. I'm new to XAML and I'm not at all clear on how to get this working. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you already know how to bind in XAML, have a look at [IValueConverter interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.ivalueconverter)

Comment: @FilippoB It's new to me, but I'm trying to use an IValueConverter implementation. However, I can't seem to get my reference to that class to resolve in the XAML. I'm tring to set the Text value to "{Binding Path=PasswordCredentialObject, Converter={StaticResource Helpers:PasswordCredentialConverter}, ConverterParameter=UserName}" and I've added a namespace reference of xmlns:Helpers="using:WindowsApp1.Helpers", but it's failing to resolve the reference.

Comment: Figured out the reference problem. I neglected to declare the static resource for the converter in my page's XAML.

Comment: If you still have problems, let me know and I'll try elaborate an answer

Answer (score 1):

this is easier than you think. Assuming this model:

```
public class UserCredentials : BindableBase
{
    string _userName = default(string);
    public string UserName { get { return _userName; } set { Set(ref _userName, value); } }

    string _password = default(string);
    public string Password { get { return _password; } set { Set(ref _password, value); } }
}
```

You can do this in your XAML:

```
<!-- login form -->
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="20, 16" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=ThisPage}">
    <TextBox Header="Username" Text="{Binding UserCredentials.UserName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <TextBox Header="Password" Text="{Binding UserCredentials.Password, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Button Click="LoginClicked" Margin="0,12,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Login</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Make sense? To help, I added this to the Sample project in the GitHub repo for Template 10, if you wanted to see it working.

Best of luck.